# How can I access the hostname in an ExpressionEngine template

Tags: expressionengine

What's the easiest way to access the HTTP host name inside an ExpressionEngine template (**without** resorting to using PHP in the template).

Has a plugin already been created to do this, or should I use some sort of global variable?

Bonus points if there is a way to access other HTTP server variables inside an ExpressionEngine template as well.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the host name or do you wish to set it somewhere for use in your templates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the hostname as a global variable and use that.  You can set the global variable in your config file with php, and then you will have access to it in the template.

Or you can use {path='site_index'}

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['global_var_name'] = 'Global var value';
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking global variables might be the way to go. For future reference, could you elaborate on how to add this to the config file?

Answer (score 3):

How about just using {site_url} which is a standard global variable?

If you want to assign a config variable then you could do:

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['gv_hostname'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

and then within your template you could call it via {gv_hostname} of course this wouldn't add the http:// before the hostname.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an addon for this called *Server Variable*
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/server-variable

```
{exp:server_var:server var="HTTP_HOST"}
```

Any of the other server variables are also available: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following code to your /system/expressionengine/config/config.php file

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['my_http_host'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

This could then be used in templates like so:

```
{my_http_host}
```

If you wanted the protocol ie. http if not https you could do this:

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['my_protocol'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
```

This could then be used in template like so:

{my_protocol}

Here is a list of [PHP Reserved Server Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)